# Run a regression on certain parts of a data frame and extract estimates + errors

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, regression

I try to run a several regressions on a selected part of a data frame.
There are 22 columns. One is "DATE", one is "INDEX" and S1, S2, S3 ... S20.

I run the regression this way:

```
Regression <- lm(as.matrix(df[c('S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S6', 'S7', 'S8', 'S9', 'S10', 'S11', 'S12', 'S13', 'S14', 'S15', 'S16', 'S17', 'S18', 'S19', 'S20')]) ~ df$INDEX)
Regression$coefficients
```

1) How can I make the code shorter? Just like using an interval to tell R: take columns S1 to S20 as explanatory variables and run the regression on them with the dependent variable INDEX.

2) Regression Formula is: a + b*INDEX + error
Then extract all the "b" estimates from the regression. Lets say the columns have 10 rows, so there must be 10 estimates.
Also extract all the errors: that must be 10 errors in each column, and a total of 10*20=200 errors in total.

Since I have no experience with R, all kind of help is welcome! Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I mixed it up: S variables are dependent and the INDEX is explanatory. S = a + b*INDEX + error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could shorten your code substantially by using `paste()` instead of manually writing out all your column names:

```
Regression <- lm(as.matrix(df[paste0("S", 1:20)]) ~ df$INDEX)
```

To access the regression estimates, use `Regression$fitted.values`. For the errors, use `Regression$residuals`.

Example using the `iris` data:

```
data(iris)
Regression <- lm(Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width ~ Petal.Length, data = iris)

head(Regression$fitted.values)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
1     4.879095    3.306775
2     4.879095    3.306775
3     4.838202    3.317354
4     4.919987    3.296197
5     4.879095    3.306775
6     5.001771    3.275039

head(Regression$residuals)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
1    0.2209054   0.1932249
2    0.0209054  -0.3067751
3   -0.1382024  -0.1173536
4   -0.3199868  -0.1961965
5    0.1209054   0.2932249
6    0.3982287   0.6249605
```

Comment: That looks great!
How can I do the same, should I have 20 columns with different names without numbers. E.g. "Sa", "Sb", "Sc", "Sd", etc. Then I could not use  [paste0("S", 1:20)]? 
How can I tell R to go into the data frame and start with column number 1 and end with column number 20, and take the columns by their full length. Maybe I think too much like an excel user, where I can select the columns and rows before making the calculation.

Comment: See @ira's answer, you can just use digits for the position of the columns in the dataframe, e.g. `df[1:20]` for the first 20.

Answer (score 4):

If you have 22 columns, just use position of the columns in the dataframe. Using the same dataset as LAP in his answer:

```
# load iris dataset
date(iris)
# run regression
Regression <- lm(as.matrix(iris[1:3]) ~ Petal.Width, data = iris)
```

This would, in your case, translate to something like:

```
# run the regression
Regression <- lm(as.matrix(df[3:22]) ~ INDEX, data = df)
```

Assuming your dependent variables are in columns 3 to 22 (and 1st column is date, second is index, or something like that)

Comment: Thanks! This is really the easiest solution from all! However, when you use it for independent variables it always includes an "as.matrix(sb[3:22])" before the variable name in the output (summary(Regression)). 
Would it be possible to avoid that?

Comment: Perhaps you could run the `as.matrix` a line above the `lm`. In that case the variable name would consist of the name of the matrix you created and the name of the column.

Comment: Good idea. This way one can choose a short prefix like "var_".